# Tkinter Radiobutton problema

Tags: python, tkinter

Hola muy buenas soy nuevo aquí y estoy aprendiendo a usar *pyhton* en *tkinter*, ahora me propuse hacer un mini proyecto de registrar usuarios con *tkinter* tipo *CRUD* con conexion *sqlite3* , me pude guiar de un youtuber , mi GUI puede guardar y eliminar usuarios sin problemas ,pero el problema surge con la función editar los campos:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import sqlite3

class usuarios():
    # connection dir property
    db_name = 'databeis.db'

    def __init__(self, raiz):

        self.root = raiz
        self.root.title("Lists Users")
        self.gender = StringVar()
        self.gender.set(None)

        miFrame = Frame(self.root,width=800, height=800)
        miFrame.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, pady=20)

        # Name Input
        Label(miFrame, text = 'user_name: ').grid(row = 1, column = 0)
        self.user_name = Entry(miFrame)
        self.user_name.focus()
        self.user_name.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

        # Password Input
        Label(miFrame, text = 'password: ').grid(row = 2, column = 0)
        self.password = Entry(miFrame)
        self.password.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

        # Name Input
        Label(miFrame, text = 'name: ').grid(row = 3, column = 0)
        self.name = Entry(miFrame)
        self.name.grid(row = 3, column = 1)


        # RADIOBUTTON GENRE
        Radiobutton(miFrame, text="Male", variable=self.gender, value="Male").grid(
            row=4, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

        Radiobutton(miFrame, text="Female", variable=self.gender, value="Female").grid(
            row=4, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

        Radiobutton(miFrame, text="Other", variable=self.gender, value="Other").grid(
            row=4, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)

        # City Input
        Label(miFrame, text = 'City: ').grid(row = 5, column = 0)
        self.city = Entry(miFrame)
        self.city.grid(row = 5, column = 1)

        # Button Add  
        Button(miFrame, text = 'Save User', command = self.add_user).grid(row = 6, columnspan = 2, sticky = W + E)
        # Button Delete
        Button(text = 'DELETE User', command= self.delete_user).grid(row = 9, column = 0, columnspan = 1, sticky = W + E)
         # Button Edit
        Button(text = 'EDIT User', command=self.edit_user).grid(row = 9, column = 2, columnspan =1 , sticky = W+E)


        # Output Messages 
        self.message = Label(text = '', fg = 'red')
        self.message.grid(row = 6, column = 1, columnspan = 1, sticky = W + E)


        # Table
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(miFrame,heigh=10,columns=("#1","#2","#3","#4"))#SI PONGO #4 SE AGREGARA UNA COLUMNA VACIA
        self.tree.grid(row = 7, column = 0, columnspan = 4 ,pady=10,sticky=W+E+N+S)
        self.tree.column("#0", width=450, minwidth=270, stretch=NO)
        self.tree.column("#1", width=150, minwidth=150, stretch=NO)
        self.tree.column("#2", width=80, minwidth=20, stretch=NO)
        self.tree.column("#3", width=80, minwidth=20, stretch=NO)
        self.tree.column("#4", width=80, minwidth=20, stretch=NO)
        self.tree.heading('#0', text = 'Username', anchor = CENTER)
        self.tree.heading('#1', text = 'Password', anchor = CENTER)
        self.tree.heading('#2', text = 'Name', anchor = CENTER)
        self.tree.heading('#3', text = 'Gender', anchor = CENTER)
        self.tree.heading('#4', text = 'City', anchor = CENTER)

        vsb = Scrollbar(miFrame, orient="vertical", command=self.tree.yview)
        vsb.grid(row=7, column=5, sticky='nse',pady=10)
        self.tree.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)

        hsb = Scrollbar(miFrame, orient="horizontal", command=self.tree.xview)
        hsb.grid(row = 8, column=0, columnspan=5, sticky = W+E)
        self.tree.configure(xscrollcommand = hsb.set)

        # Filling the Rows
        self.get_user()

        # Function to Execute Database Querys
    def run_query(self, query, parameters = ()):
        with sqlite3.connect(self.db_name) as conn:
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            result = cursor.execute(query, parameters)
            conn.commit()
        return result

        # Get User from Database
    def get_user(self):
        # cleaning Table 
        records = self.tree.get_children()
        for element in records:
            self.tree.delete(element)
        # getting data
        query = 'SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY user DESC'
        db_rows = self.run_query(query)
        # filling data
        for row in db_rows:
            self.tree.insert('', 0, text = row[1], values = (row[2],row[3],row[4],row[5]))

    # User Input Validation
    def validation(self):
        return len(self.user_name.get()) != 0 and len(self.password.get()) != 0 and len(self.name.get()) != 0 and len(self.gender.get()) != 0 and len(self.city.get()) != 0

    def add_user(self):
        if self.validation():
            query = 'INSERT INTO users VALUES(NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'
            parameters =  (self.user_name.get(), self.password.get(), self.name.get(), self.gender.get(), self.city.get())
            self.run_query(query, parameters)
            self.message['text'] = 'User {} added Successfully'.format(self.user_name.get())
            self.user_name.delete(0, END)
            self.password.delete(0, END)
            self.name.delete(0, END)
            self.gender.set(None)
            self.city.delete(0, END)
        else:
            self.message['text'] = 'All fields are Required'
        self.get_user()

    def delete_user(self):
        self.message['text'] = ''
        try:
           self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['text'][0]
        except IndexError as e:
            self.message['text'] = 'Please select a Record'
            return
        self.message['text'] = ''
        user_name = self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['text']
        query = 'DELETE FROM users WHERE user = ?'
        self.run_query(query, (user_name, ))
        self.message['text'] = 'Record {} deleted Successfully'.format(user_name)
        self.get_user()

    def edit_user(self):
        self.message['text'] = ''
        try:
            self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['values'][0]
        except IndexError as e:
            self.message['text'] = 'Please, select Record'
            return
        user_name = self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['text']
        old_password = self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['values'][0]
        old_name = self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['values'][1]
        old_gender = self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['values'][2]
        old_city = self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['values'][3]
        self.edit_wind = Toplevel()
        self.edit_wind.title = 'Edit User'

        # Old username
        Label(self.edit_wind, text = 'Old username:').grid(row = 0, column = 1)
        Entry(self.edit_wind, textvariable = StringVar(self.edit_wind, value = user_name ), state = 'readonly').grid(row = 0, column = 2)
        # New username
        Label(self.edit_wind, text = 'New username:').grid(row = 1, column = 1)
        new_username = Entry(self.edit_wind)
        new_username.grid(row = 1, column = 2)

        # Old password
        Label(self.edit_wind, text = 'Old Pass:').grid(row = 2, column = 1)
        Entry(self.edit_wind, textvariable = StringVar(self.edit_wind, value = old_password), state = 'readonly').grid(row = 2, column = 2)
        # New password
        Label(self.edit_wind, text = 'New Pass:').grid(row = 3, column = 1)
        new_password = Entry(self.edit_wind)
        new_password.grid(row = 3, column = 2)

        # Old genre
        Label(self.edit_wind, text = 'Old Genre:').grid(row = 4, column = 1)
        Entry(self.edit_wind, textvariable = StringVar(self.edit_wind, value = old_gender), state = 'readonly').grid(row = 4, column = 2)

        # New GENRE
        self.new_gender = StringVar()
        self.new_gender.set(None)

        Radiobutton(self.edit_wind,text="Male", variable=self.new_gender, value="Male").grid(
            row=5, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

        Radiobutton(self.edit_wind,text="Female", variable=self.new_gender, value="Female").grid(
            row=5, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

        Radiobutton(self.edit_wind, text="Other", variable=self.new_gender, value="Other").grid(
            row=5, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)

        # Old name
        Label(self.edit_wind, text = 'Old name:').grid(row = 6, column = 1)
        Entry(self.edit_wind, textvariable = StringVar(self.edit_wind, value = old_name), state = 'readonly').grid(row = 6, column = 2)
        # New name
        Label(self.edit_wind, text = 'New name:').grid(row = 7, column = 1)
        new_name = Entry(self.edit_wind)
        new_name.grid(row = 7, column = 2)


        # Old city
        Label(self.edit_wind, text = 'Old city:').grid(row = 8, column = 1)
        Entry(self.edit_wind, textvariable = StringVar(self.edit_wind, value = old_city), state = 'readonly').grid(row = 8, column = 2)
        # New city
        Label(self.edit_wind, text = 'New city:').grid(row = 9, column = 1)
        new_city = Entry(self.edit_wind)
        new_city.grid(row = 9, column = 2)


        Button(self.edit_wind, text = 'Update', command = lambda: self.edit_records(new_username.get(), user_name, new_password.get(), old_password, new_gender.get(), old_gender, new_name.get(), old_name, new_city.get(), old_city)).grid(
            row = 10, column = 2, sticky = W)

        self.edit_wind.mainloop()

    def edit_records(self, new_username, user_name, new_password, old_password, new_gender, old_gender, new_name, old_name, new_city, old_city):
        query = 'UPDATE usuarios SET user = ?, password = ?, name = ?, gender = ?, city = ? WHERE user = ? AND password = ? AND name = ? AND genre = ? AND city = ?'
        parameters = (new_username, new_password, new_gender, new_name, new_city, user_name, old_pasword, old_gender, old_name, old_city)
        self.run_query(query, parameters)
        self.edit_wind.destroy()
        self.message['text'] = 'Record {} updated successfylly'.format(user_name)
        self.get_user()





if __name__ == "__main__":
    raiz = Tk()
    aplicacion = usuarios(raiz)
    raiz.mainloop()
```

El problema me dice esto y si `self.new_gender = StringVar()` lo estoy definiendo ,la verdad es que no se como puedo solucionarlo , he intentado eliminar `radiobutton` haber que pasa , y si funciona correctamente pero quisiera implementar `radiobutton` para los géneros en este miniproyecto que me propuse.

> ```
>  **Button(self.edit_wind, text = 'Update', command = lambda: 
>      self.edit_records(new_username.get(), user_name, new_password.get(),
>    old_password, new_gender.get(), old_gender, new_name.get(), old_name,
>    new_city.get(), old_city)).grid(
>          NameError: name 'new_gender' is not defined**
> ```

Aqui:

```
    Button(self.edit_wind, text = 'Update', command = lambda: self.edit_records(new_username.get(), user_name, new_password.get(), old_password, new_gender.get(), old_gender, new_name.get(), old_name, new_city.get(), old_city)).grid(
        row = 10, column = 2, sticky = W)

    self.edit_wind.mainloop()

def edit_records(self, new_username, user_name, new_password, old_password, new_gender, old_gender, new_name, old_name, new_city, old_city):
    query = 'UPDATE usuarios SET user = ?, password = ?, name = ?, gender = ?, city = ? WHERE user = ? AND password = ? AND name = ? AND genre = ? AND city = ?'
    parameters = (new_username, new_password, new_gender, new_name, new_city, user_name, old_pasword, old_gender, old_name, old_city)
    self.run_query(query, parameters)
    self.edit_wind.destroy()
    self.message['text'] = 'Record {} updated successfylly'.format(user_name)
    self.get_user()
```

La conexión con *sqlite3* y mi tabla están bien , les agradecería que me ayuden, he estado intentando solucionarlo pero no encuentro en que fallo.

Comment: La variable `new_gender`  no es definida en el método  no existe, es `self.new_gender` (atributo de instancia).

Comment: Gracias , no tenia en cuenta eso, que si era atributo de instancia voy a leer mas teoria sobre POO ! ya lo pude solucionar porfin , algunas cosas aparte de eso , era con el orden campos cuando hacia conexion a sqlite3, y otras cosas triviales que se me paso desapercibido.